# Integer Array index

Tags: java

I have an array with some `integers` in it. I want to check if a given `integer` is in it or not. Other than using a `for` loop to check one by one is there a way using `indexOf` method in java? [ -1 if not in it, else the index]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `indexOf` method on arrays in Java. Your main options are:

- write the method (for example using a for loop)
- sort the array and use `Arrays.binarySearch(array, number)`
- use a collection, such as a `HashSet<Integer>` and the `contains` method.

Comment: Surely `binarySearch` would fail on two separate `Integer` instances for the same underlying value?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If it's an `int[]` (which is my understanding), then there's no problem. If it's an `Integer[]`, the contract is "*If the array contains multiple elements equal to the specified object, there is no guarantee which one will be found.*", so it should still return a value that is `>=0`.

Comment: For some reason I read it as an array of `Integer`. But it's an issue with the question, not your answer; you can read "I got a array with some `integers` in it." either way. :-)

Comment: Which method is smoother ? using `for` loop or using `Arrays.binarySearch(array, number)`

Comment: @SabareeshAP Define "smoother" !

Comment: the one works faster when there is too many integers in an array to check. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @SabareeshAP It depends how many numbers you have and how often you call the method. If you only need to check that one number is present, then use a for loop. If you need to check a few numbers, and the array is small (say < 1000 numbers), I'd probably use binary search. If the array is larger or you need to check the presence of many numbers, I'd use a Set. In the end, the best way to get your answer is to benchmark each option and check which is better for your specific use case.